# Unable to execute Jupyter Notebook from browser - UsageError: Line magic function `%profile` not found

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, apple-silicon

I am trying to set-up Notebook on my Mac.  It is a new M2 Mac, if that makes a difference.  Previously, I had followed the same steps to set-up the notebook on a Intel chip Mac successfully.

I have installed Python 3.10, created a virtual environment and installed `jupyter notebook`.  When I start the notebook on the terminal, there is no error.  It also automatically opens `http://localhost:8888/tree` in the browser and I can create a new notebook.  But when I try to execute below commands in the cell -

```
%profile saml
%idle_timeout 15
```

I get the below error

```
UsageError: Line magic function `%profile` not found.
```

There is no other error in the browser or on the terminal from where I started the notebook.  There is no error or stack trace on the terminal

What should I check to identify the actual error?  Or, how can I resolve the issue and get it working??

**Update**

Added versions

```
jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.14.0
ipykernel        : 6.25.0
ipywidgets       : 8.1.0
jupyter_client   : 8.3.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.1
jupyter_server   : 2.7.0
jupyterlab       : 4.0.4
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.7.3
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 7.0.2
qtconsole        : 5.4.3
traitlets        : 5.9.0
```

Link for docs for IPython 8.14 - [IPython 8.14 docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/8.14.0/interactive/magics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is for an interactive AWS (Amazon Web Services) session.  You will first need to install AWS Glue, which includes the `%profile` line magic.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/interactive-sessions.html

Comment: Thank you.  That was the issue.  Once I installed the interactive AWS Glue, it worked